# How to adjust the size of data gridview ASP

Tags: asp.net

I am using VS2019.

I am new to web development.

I have a gridview which is displaying information from my db. I'm currently having issues with resizing the gridview as my buttons are being made small.

I would like to know how to ensure the gridview resizes automatically.

Thanks

Below is my ASP Code:

```
 <link href="Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%">
         <div class="rows">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <asp:GridView   ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mydatagrid" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" Width="991px" OnRowCommand="OnRowCommand"  >
             <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="User Name"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_displayName" HeaderText="Display Name"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="user_userPartition" HeaderText="Partition"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="group_name" HeaderText="Group"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="createdDate" HeaderText="Created Date"  />
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False"  >
                        <ItemTemplate >
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve" OnClick = "Row_Selected" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CssClass="button-container" Visible="True" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Decline" Text="Decline" OnClick = "Row_Selected" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CssClass="button-container-decline" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust the grid by adding ItemStyle-width="10%"

Thanks